# If Cell is found in range than change cell color else leave white

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have attempted several searches on several websites and I am not able to find the answer that actually applies to my work

I have worksheet A, B, and C

Sheet An is used as a list to store data
Sheet B Refers to this data
Sheet C Refers to this data

If Cell A2 from Sheet A has an exact Match In Range From Sheet B or C than color if not leave default white

The following is the code I attempted based on the answer received.

I used the suggested "A" column and attempted to make the statement true (changed cell in column A of Route 2 to match cell A2 in Property List), I was unable to get the cell to change to green

```
Sub main()
    Dim shtA As Worksheet, shtB As Worksheet, shtC As Worksheet, shtD As Worksheet
    Set shtA = Worksheets("Property List") 'change "A" to your actual Sheet A name
    Set shtB = Worksheets("Route 2") 'change "B" to your actual Sheet A name
    Set shtC = Worksheets("Route 3") 'change "C" to your actual Sheet A name
    Set shtD = Worksheets("Route 4E") 'change "C" to your actual Sheet A name

    With shtA.Range("A2")
        .Interior.Color = IIf(Not IsThere(shtB, .Value) And Not IsThere(shtC, .Value), vbGreen, vbWhite) 'change 'vbGreen' to your actual color to mark the match
    End With
End Sub
```

```
Function IsThere(sht As Worksheet, val As Variant) As Boolean
    With sht
         IsThere = Not .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Find(what:=val, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you taken the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). While you're at it, check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section too. Now, what have you tried and your specific issue?

Comment: Simply use conditional formatting.

Comment: I cant get conditional formatting to work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

you could go like follows:

```
Sub main()
    Dim shtA As Worksheet, shtB As Worksheet, shtC As Worksheet
    Set shtA = Worksheets("A") 'change "A" to your actual Sheet A name
    Set shtB = Worksheets("B") 'change "B" to your actual Sheet A name
    Set shtC = Worksheets("C") 'change "C" to your actual Sheet A name

    With shtA.Range("A2")
        .Interior.Color = IIf(Not IsThere(shtB, .value) And Not IsThere(shtC, .value), vbGreen, vbWhite) 'change 'vbGreen' to your actual color to mark the match
    End With
End Sub

Function IsThere(sht As Worksheet, val As Variant) As Boolean
    With sht
         IsThere = Not .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Find(what:=val, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing
    End With
End Function
```

In function `IsThere` I assumed that the match is to be searched in column "A" of passed worksheet. If not, change "A2" and "A" to your actual column reference

Comment: Unfortunately I am not getting this to work out for me. I attempted to just use column A if the sheet I'm looking for. and i couldn't get the cell to change colors. I then attempted to add the other multiple rows that i need to search in each worksheet. I am afraid I am at a loss of what to change

Comment: I am attempting to post my change of code but its too long to post